# How to call servlet class from HTML form

Tags: html, forms, servlets

I created one web application project. It contains a servlet class and a HTML form. How do I call the servlet class from the HTML form?

Answer (score 28):

Just create a class extending [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and annotate it with [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) on a certain URL pattern.

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

Or when you're still on Servlet 2.5 or older (the annotation was new since Servlet 3.0), then register the servlet as `<servlet>` in `web.xml` and map it on a certain URL pattern via `<servlet-mapping>`.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then, just let the HTML link or form action point to an URL which matches the `url-pattern` of the servlet.

```html
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Login</a>
```

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When using submit buttons, make sure that you use `type="submit"` and not `type="button"`. Explanation on the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` part can be found in this related question and answer: [How to use servlet URL pattern in HTML form action without getting HTTP 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377).

Links and forms with `method="get"` will invoke `doGet()` method of the servlet. You usually use this method to preprocess a request "on page load".

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...
}
```

Forms with `method="post"` will invoke `doPost()` method of the servlet. You usually use this method to postprocess a request with user-submitted form data (collect request parameters, convert and validate them, update model, invoke business action and finally render response).

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...
}
```

To learn more about servlets and to find more concrete examples, head to [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Noted should be that you can also use a JSP file instead of a plain HTML file. JSP allows you to interact with backend  via EL expressions while producing HTML output, and to use taglibs like JSTL to control the flow. See also [our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info).

Comment: An exception was been thrown. Read the stacktrace/logs and fix code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For instance I create a login.html like that

```
<div class="container">

    <form method = "post" class="form-signin" role="form" action="LoginServlet">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "username" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name = "password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign in">
  </form>

</div>
```

Between  tags I call LoginServlet by defining method as "post".