# Call a Servlet from a jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

Can we call a servlet from a JSP, come back and display the response data we get from the servlet in the same JSP? Is it possible to do that?

Basically, I have a pop up in which the user gives some input. I pass this to the servlet and the servlet gives me an acknowledgement number. I would like to display this acknowledgement number in the same pop up.

In the meantime, during which the servlet gives the response, I can display an hour glass in the pop up. Is this possible?

Someone please help me with an example please.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649722/how-to-call-servlet-through-a-jsp-page

Comment: Don't think of it as calling a servlet from a jsp. That's really not what you would be doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
You can submit form in your popup jsp and then forward to the same JSP from servlet.
**Option 2**
You can use ajax and call servlet and then send response (e.g. JSON) back from servlet and update what you need using javascript, jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can call servlet from jsp.

To call servlet from jsp use,

```
<form action="../Your_servlet_name_in_web.xml_file">
```

And to call JSP from servlet use,

```
response.sendRedirect("Your_JSP_NAME.jsp");
```

[For calling servlet from jsp](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/136199/how-to-call-servlet-from-jsp)

Hope this will help you.