# getting NullPointerException when patching to a jsp file within a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have Apache Tomcat web server embedded inside a normal java desktop application. [Embedding Tomcat](http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Embedding-Tomcat.pdf).

I have added multiple servlets and mappings within my application:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat(); // creating a tomcat instance
            tomcat.setPort(8080); // set the port
            // Creating a context:
            File docBase = new File("src/");
            Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", docBase.getAbsolutePath());
            // Adding servlet
            Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "Input", new InputHandler());
            ctx.addServletMapping("/input", "Input");
            tomcat.start();
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (LifecycleException | InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `InputHandler` class source code which is a `HttpServlet` type:

```
public class InputHandler extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // This is where I have problem
        // I think because it can't find the index.jsp file getRequestDispatcher
        // returns null as described in [getRequestDispatcher() documentation][2]
        request.getRequestDispatcher("src/web/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    // ... and also doPost()...
}
```

[`getRequestDespatcher()` Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)

and my project structure is like this:

```
+ Test
|
+---+ Source Packages
|   |
|   +---+ test
|   |   |
|   |   +--- InputHandler.java
|   |   |
|   |   +--- Test.java
|   |
|   +---+ web
|       | 
|       +--- index.jsp
|
+---+ Libraries
```

I did everything as in the attached link [1](http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Embedding-Tomcat.pdf). everything is fine except that a `NullPointerException` is thrown when executing bellow line in the `InputHandler.processRequest()` method:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("src/web/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I tried also below cases but nothing changes:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("../web/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(AbsolutePathToIndex.jsp).forward(request, response);
```

What is wrong with this?

Note: I am not familiar with Java Enterprise Edition

Comment: Where are you making the JSP talk to the servlet.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649722/how-to-call-servlet-through-a-jsp-page

Comment: What does your WAR file/directory look like? It's generally different than your "project" structure.