# Checking for sessions in servlet or jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Suppose I have a servlet that processes logins. When the login is successful the user will create a session for this user. Then redirects to a homepage.

Let's say the homepage has a link "view all". This link calls a servlet, viewall.html to process all the data from the database then redirect to a jsp page (viewall.jsp) that will display the data from the servlet.

Somewhere from the servlet viewall.html to the jsp viewall.jsp, I would like to have code that looks like this:

```
if (session attribute user is null) {
    // redirect to the login page
} else {
    // if in the servlet, retrieve the data from the database
    // if in the jsp, display the data
}
```

What is the better way to check if there is a session, on the servlet or the jsp? Note I know about filters, let's say the project can't use filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same using a servlet of a filter. The general way is :

- in the servlet that processes login you

  - create a new session

    ```
    Session old = request.getSession(false); // first invalidate old if it exists
    if (old != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    Session session = request.getSession(true); // next create one
    ```
  - put the user id as attribute of the session

    ```
    session.setAttribute("USERID", userId);
    ```
- then in the element (filter of servlet) where you want to know whether you have a registered user :

  ```
  Session = request.getSession(false);
  if ((session == null) or (session.getAttribute("USERID") == null)) {
      response.sendRedirect(homeUrl);
      return; // no need to process further (if in a filter no need to go down the chain)
  }
  ```
- in the servlet **after controlling you have a logged on user**, forward to the jsp

  request.getRequestDispacher("/path/to/displayer.jsp").forward(request, response);

That's all ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check this before creating, then do so:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
 if (session == null) {
  // Not created .
  session = request.getSession();
  } else {
// Already created.
  }
```

If you don't care about checking this after creating, then you can also do so:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 if (session.isNew()) {
  // newly  created.
 } else {
// Already created.
  }
```

Comment: But where should I check it? On the servlets, on the jsp, or both is fine?

Comment: Yes you can use on Servlet and JSP . inside JSP page you can use servlet code insde <%  %> tag  as well .

Comment: so you mean if checking for session either on servlets or jsp is just a personal preference?

Comment: Yes you can if you want more info go : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649722/how-to-call-servlet-through-a-jsp-page

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if(session.getAttribute("sessionname")==null)

{
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
else
{
String activeUser=session.getAttribute("sessionname").toString();
}
```

I hope it helps you