# How can I enter a Servlet right after entering the JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

How can I enter a Servlet right after entering the JSP page? Is it possible to get the requested parameters in the current page after entering the Servlet? After clicking an anchor tag, I want to get information using Servlet to my current JSP file. How do I that? What do I have to add in my anchor tag before going to my desired page?

Current page - `Profile.jsp`

```
<a href="Profile.jsp">View Profile</a>    
<a href="ReportGeneration.jsp">View Report Generation</a>
<a href="Contact.jsp">Contact Us</a>
```

Desired page - `ReportGeneration.jsp`
Servlet - `ReportProcess.java`

I want to print the information from ReportProcess servlet to ReportGeneration.jsp when "View Report Generation" tag is clicked.

Comment: Rather than linking to the jsp, link to the servlet

Comment: if possible refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455627/how-include-servlet-output-to-jsp-file

Comment: @AshokKumarN can I link the two servlets to each other? Including servlet1 to servlet2 and including servlet2 to servlet1?

Comment: @ss1 can you have it in one servlet instead of two servlet

Answer (score 0):

Include the servlet result into the ReportGeneration.jsp like this

```
<jsp:include page="/ReportProcess" />
```

here ReportProcess consider as a servlet URL in this area you will get the servlet output in this tag area

if you want the servlet output in profile.jsp

instead of this

```
<a href="ReportGeneration.jsp">View Report Generation</a>
```

use this

```
<jsp:include page="/ReportProcess" />
```

as suggested by @Scary Wombat