# Eclipse: jsp:include action with servlet

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, jspinclude

Well, here again strucked on a suppoused no problem.
I have a simple servlet "Myservlet.java" that prints a string
(Dynamic Web Project name is "JspCallingServlet" and its context root is "/")
[DynamicWebProject Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay14Y.png)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(
        name="MyServlet",
        urlPatterns="/MyServlet"
        )
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

... omitted code

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("... I'M MyServlet ...");
    }

}
```

And it works since if i "Run As/Run on Server" it shows
[servlet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkng7.png)

So i thought that i could easily call it within a jsp with the include action,
setting as page the servlet url

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using servlet into a jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    Using: MyServlet.java
    <br />
    <jsp:include page="/MyServlet" />
</body>
</html>
```

but why on hell the

```
<jsp:include page="/MyServlet" />
```

doesn't compile, and the message says

```
Fragment "/MyServlet" was not found at expected path /JspCallingServlet/WebContent/MyServlet
```

Why bothering the WebContent folder when it's supposed to open the "page" URL mapped to the servlet?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:S i found an answer by myself.

I was somehow misguided by the answer i found at
[How to call servlet through a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649722/how-to-call-servlet-through-a-jsp-page)
before posting the very question i made...

It seems - at least that's what happens to me - that the right "action" to use in order to include a servlet is the "forward" action:
not the "include" one.

Ie the right .jsp is the following

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using servlet into a jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    Using "jsp:include" fails, while using "jsp:forward" works
    <br />
    <jsp:forward page="/MyServlet" />               <%-- WORKING --%>
    <%-- <jsp:include page="/MyServlet" /> --%>     <%-- NOT WORKING --%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<jsp:include page="/MyServlet">`should be changed to `<jsp:include page="/xxx.jsp">`