# how can i call Servlet from JSP file ? because it is direcly welcome file to login page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how can i call multiple Servlets from JSP file ? it is set to go for welcome file when it starts in and it navigates it to login and registration page if anyone logins it is navigated to the **user.jsp** file and in **user.jsp**  page i need to load the information which is in the Servlet **doGet**  method ? and in the servlet i have also used to request dispatch

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("abc.jsp");
```

but it is not working until i am not starting servlet and navigating to **user.jsp** my own self.

Comment: Possibly has been already answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649755/923509

Comment: i have seen this but it does not solve my problem i have to call simultaneously two servlets

Comment: dear i have a userIndex.jsp where i wanna to fetch two servlets one is fetching and sending User Information and other is sending the books information. when i am logining it is showing me user information but not books class so how can i call both at same time ??

Comment: One single HTTP request can't be forwarded to two different servlets. Similarly, if you have a login form, it will be sent with POST to one single URL. Maybe you could make user.jsp load the books information related to that logged user?