# How to run servlet code when jsp is running

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to run servlet code when i run jsp page without performing any action.
I want to hit Servlet page automatically when i execute jsp page.

Comment: There is already a really good answer to such question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649755/1731754.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem (http://xyproblem.info/). What do you try to achieve?

Comment: if you want to do something without do any action in `jsp`, you can use methods of servlet such as  `init()` which is called when the servlet created for the first time