# Error HTTP Status 404. The requested resource is not available. [Netbeans]

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat8, netbeans-8

I do a project Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion using netbeans with Tomcat 8.0.37
when i try to run project, i get a issue HTTP Satus 404.

My index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Please enter Fahrenheit temperature:</h3><p>

<form action="/conv/test"> 
Temperature(F) : <input type="text" name="temperature"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml

```
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>doGetMethod.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My TestServlet.java

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException 
    {       
        String temperature = req.getParameter("temperature");
            DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

            try 
            {
              double tempF = Double.parseDouble(temperature);
              String tempC = twoDigits.format((tempF -32)*5.0/9.0);

              PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
          out.println("<html>");
          out.println("<head>");
          out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
          out.println("<h3>" + temperature + " Fahrenheit is 
                 converted to " + tempC + " Celsius</h3><p>");              
          out.println("</body>");
          out.println("</html>");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {   

              res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
              "There was an input error");           
            }       
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue !

I apologize for not being word-perfect in English.

Comment: can you post url which you are using for accessing servlet.

Comment: @cody123 http://localhost:8080/Conv/ and http://localhost:8080/conv/test?temperature=12

Answer (score 2):

You should access the index.html at localhost:8080/contextRoot/index.html. The action associated to the form should map to the servlet, so it should be action="/test". The servlet-class tag in the web.xml should specify your servlet class full name such as mypackage.TestServlet. You could avoid using a web.xml and save you some time by using annotation on the Servlet class as well explained here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets004.htm#BNAFU. Also look here for a similar example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395262/6848537

Comment: I have also found an example where the action maps to the url without a slash: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets016.htm