# How to write to a file in Java using Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, netbeans

I am creating a Java Web Application which takes data from a HTML form and saves it to a text file using a Servlet. However when I run the application I cannot see the text file anywhere so I am unsure if it was created successfully or not. Does anyone have any ideas why the file is not appearing?

Here is my code for the HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register Customer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "regcustomer" method = "get" action = "CustomerServlet" >
        Customer Name
        <input type="text" name="customerName"> <br>
        Customer Address 
        <input type="text" name="customerAddress"> <br> 
        Telephone Number
        <input type="text" name="telNo"> <br>
        Email
        <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
        Cost per KG shipped
        <input type="text" name="costPKG"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"> <br> <br>

        <a href="index.html">Back</a>
        </form>
</body>
```

And here is my code for the servlet:

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
String customerName;
customerName = request.getParameter("customerName");
String customerAddress = request.getParameter("customerAddress");
String telNo;
telNo = request.getParameter("telNo");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String costPKG = request.getParameter("costPKG");

try{
File file = new File("C:/xyz.txt");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file,true);
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream)) {
    out.write(customerName+" "+customerAddress+" "+telNo+" "+email+" 
"+costPKG);
    out.newLine();
}
pw.println("File is created successfully");
}

catch (IOException e){
System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: This might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395251/how-to-call-servlet-class-from-html-form)

Comment: should map your servlet first in web.xml

Comment: Your title is totally incorrect

Comment: How is it incorrect? I can change it if I need to

Comment: *I keep getting an error which says "TTP Status 404* - how is this related to writing to a file?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question as I am no longer getting the error

Comment: Try closing your `filewriter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the line:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/CustomerServlet" })
```

before:

```
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Note: If you are using old container (not implemented Servlet 3.0, like Tomcat 6.0), then you have to edit web.xml.

Comment: what if WebApplication is not 3.0 and above? below doesn't support annotation configs.

Comment: I have added the line and edited web.xml and I no longer get an error, however I cannot find the text file. Do you have any idea where I could find it? Is there something else I could change ("C:/xyz.txt") to?

Comment: `C:/xyz.txt` might be locked or not writable.

Comment: I've solved the problem, thanks everyone for your help :)

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I removed "C:/" and just typed xyz.txt. Then I searched for it on my computer and found the file location